# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session', sparkdl errors

Tags: tensorflow, apache-spark, keras, pyspark, deep-learning

I am trying to use deep learning in pyspark but it's not working.

here is my code :

```
featurizer = DeepImageFeaturizer(inputCol="image",
                                 outputCol="features",
                                 modelName="InceptionV3")

lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=5, regParam=0.03, 
                        elasticNetParam=0.5, labelCol="label")
sparkdn = Pipeline(stages=[featurizer, lr])
spark_model = sparkdn.fit(train)
```

The last part of The error:

```
File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sparkdl/transformers/keras_applications.py:45, in KerasApplicationModel.getModelData(self, featurize)
     44 def getModelData(self, featurize):
---> 45     sess = tf.Session()
     46     with sess.as_default():
     47         K.set_learning_phase(0)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'
```

I tried to uninstall and install tf.
also I am running pyspark with deep-learning package:

```
pyspark --packages databricks:spark-deep-learning:0.1.0-spark2.1-s_2.11
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use the `DeepImageFeaturizer` transformer from the `spark-deep-learning package`. This error usually occurs if you have an old version of TensorFlow installed on your system, or if your using a version of TensorFlow that is not compatible with the `spark-deep-learning package`.

Try the following:

Uninstall the current version of TensorFlow using `pip uninstall tensorflow`.

Then install the latest version of TensorFlow: `pip install tensorflow`.

Make sure that the version of TensorFlow that you are using is compatible with the `spark-deep-learning package`. According to the documentation it requires TensorFlow 1.6 or later.

Try setting the environment variable `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` to 3 before running your code. This can help suppress some TensorFlow warnings and errors.

Comment: I just did it now, and still the same error occurs.  this is the version of TensorFlow: 2.11.0